# Jenkins CI dashboard - direct links to deployed web applications

Tags: continuous-integration, hudson, jenkins

In Jenkins CI Dashboard i have a few defined jobs that deploy webapplication to tomcat server. Is there any way to put direct links to those deployed applications? sth like that:
below job name there is link like http://jenkins.ci:8081/webapp1

In ideal situation I'd like those links to be visible right after build is successfully done.
Anyone knows how to achieve sth like that?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Sidebar-Link+Plugin